# Can't call another file within a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I'm trying to run a script which is running every couple of seconds. 
Let me show you first my code:

```
<div id="deadlinetask"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(swapImages,5000); 

    function swapImages(){
        $("#deadlinetask").load("pages/jquery/task-expiration.php");
    }
    });
</script>
```

And task-expiration file looks like this:

```
<?php

//let´s display the alarm 15 minutes prior deadline
if($timeleft <= 21) { 

?>

<!-- Display this modal window if less the x minutes --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Task expiration</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <div>
      <h3 class="text-center">Your task "<?=$row['title'];?> is about to expire</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<audio id="foobar" src="https://easynote.io/what-friends-are-for.ogg" preload="auto"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');

var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
sample.play();

});
</script>


<?php } ?>
```

Now I have just tried to insert text like hello and it its being refreshed every 5 seconds. 
Another thing is if I try to replace the first code above with:

```
<div id="deadlinetask"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#deadlinetask").load("pages/jquery/task-expiration.php");
    });
</script>
```

Then the modal popup shows on page load. 
So finally to my question. 
Why isn't this working when I call it from a function? Could someone give maybe an example how to solve this?

Comment: hey bud, do you maybe have any tips what i need to change, an example of the code, since I'm really a noob on JS :(

Comment: `@ochi` you don't have to specify a function. It could be that your localhost page is somehow using FTP instead of HTTP. Try `.load('http://localhost/pages/jquery/tastk-expiration.php')` to see if this is the problem.

Comment: @PHPglue, I stand corrected, those other parameters are optional - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to post that I found the problem and thank you @ochi and everyone else for helping.

So The solution to the problem was to change

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

in the file task-expiration.php

Thank you sooo much for all help!